# Using same root header in subfolder wp blog - Header disapears on Single Posts

Tags: directory, blog, server

I have made a website where I have a wordpress blog in a sub-directory (/blog)

I have used

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/header.php");
```

to include my header from my root directory so that my blog matches the rest of the website (built using bootstrap)

However, if you go to my website

it appears to be okay until you click on a blog post and then on the page of the post you have to refresh the page for the navbar and header to appear

Am I missing something here? I have been confused for hours trying out different things with no luck!

I do not want to use the wp header as that will require a lot of time to style it to match mine and would rather just use my main site header from the root file. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

**NOTE:**

I am using jquery mobile in my main website in the root folder and hence the links are in my header for it. When I remove jquery mobile from the header it works fine. How can I get around this?

Comment: Tested in chrome and it looks to work ok

Comment: I have taken jquery mobile off and hence I have a javascript error on dev console in chrome :(

Comment: but with jquery mobile which I use across the root site the problem above persists